# Help with latex flow chart

Tags: flow-charts

Can anyone help me here, I need to have enough space between the first column of the flow chart and the second column of the flow chart. As you can see the blocks are overlapping.

```
-----------------------
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.3cm and 1.5cm, 
fmt/.style={draw, minimum width=2.5cm},
fmtw/.style={draw, minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=0.75cm}][t]% introducing fmt for simplification

% deleted duplicate draw options
% cleaning up the code a little bit

\node[fmt,
    rounded rectangle,
    minimum height=1cm]         (block1) {START};

\node[fmtw,
    below=of block1,
    minimum height=0.75cm]      (block2) {block1};
        
\node[fmt,
    below=of block2,
    minimum width=1.0cm,
    minimum height=1cm]         (block3) {Track the highest Peak during the billing Cycle};     

\node[fmt,
    diamond,
    below=of block3,
    inner sep=0]                (block4) {block3};
 
\node[fmtw, left=of block4, 
        xshift=-5mm]            (block5) {block4};% shift to left
 
\node[fmtw,  below=of block4]   (block6) {block5};

\node[fmtw, below=of block6]    (block7) {block6};
    
\node[fmt, diamond, 
  below=of block7, inner sep=0] (block8) {block7};
 
\node[fmtw, left=of block8, 
            xshift=-5mm]        (block9) {block8};% shift to left

\node[fmtw, below=of block8]    (block10) {block9};      

\node[fmtw, right=of block2]    (block11) {block10};      

\node[fmtw, below=of block11]   (block12) {Send requests for each aggregator (Section 3)}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block12]   (block13) {block12}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block13]   (block14) {block13}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block14]   (block15) {block14}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block15]   (block16) {block15}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block16]   (block17) {block16}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block17]   (block18) {block17}; 

\node[fmt, diamond,
    below=of block18, 
    inner sep=0]                (block19) {block18};
    
\node[fmtw, left=of block19, 
        xshift=-5mm]            (block20) {block19};% moving a little to left

 
\node[fmtw, below=of block19]   (block21) {END};   
    
% Arrows
  \draw[-latex] (block1) edge (block2);
  \draw[-latex] (block2) edge (block3);
  \draw[-latex] (block3) edge (block4);
  \draw[-latex] (block4) edge node[pos=0.3,inner sep=0pt]{Yes}(block6)
     (block4) edge node[pos=0.15,inner sep=0pt]{No}(block5);
  \draw[-latex] (block6) edge (block7);  
  \draw[-latex] (block7) edge (block8);        
  \draw[-latex] (block8) edge node[pos=0.3,inner sep=0pt]{Yes}(block9)
     (block8) edge node[pos=0.25,inner sep=0pt]{No}(block10);
% \draw[->] (block10) -| (block11);  
  \draw[-latex] (block11) edge (block12);  
  \draw[->] (block12) edge (block13);
  \draw[->] (block13) edge (block14);
  \draw[->] (block14) edge (block15);
  \draw[->] (block15) edge (block16);
  \draw[->] (block16) edge (block17);
  \draw[->] (block17) edge (block18);
  \draw[->] (block18) edge (block19);
  \draw[-latex] (block19) edge node[pos=0.3,inner sep=0pt]{Yes}(block20)
     (block19) edge node[pos=0.25,inner sep=0pt]{No}(block21);
%     \draw[->] (block20) |- (block7);
     
  % Tom's comment
  \draw[->] (block10.east) --++(0.15cm,0cm) |- (block11.west); 
  \draw[->] (block20.west) --++(-4cm,0cm) |- (block7.west);
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Do you wanna them to be one line or multiple lines in the block?

Comment: thanks. one line if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to fix Yes and No in the flow chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think multiple lines will be better. Like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.3cm, 
fmt/.style={draw, minimum width=2.5cm},
fmtw/.style={draw, minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=0.75cm}][t]% introducing fmt for simplification

% deleted duplicate draw options
% cleaning up the code a little bit

\node[fmt,
    rounded rectangle,
    minimum height=1cm]         (block1) {START};

\node[fmtw,
    below=of block1,
    minimum height=0.75cm]      (block2) {block1};
        
\node[fmtw,
    below=of block2,align=center,text width=3cm]         (block3) {Track the highest Peak during the billing Cycle};     

\node[fmt,
    diamond,
    below=of block3,
    inner sep=0]                (block4) {block3};
 
\node[fmtw, left=of block4, 
        xshift=-5mm]            (block5) {block4};% shift to left
 
\node[fmtw,  below=of block4]   (block6) {block5};

\node[fmtw, below=of block6]    (block7) {block6};
    
\node[fmt, diamond, 
  below=of block7, inner sep=0] (block8) {block7};
 
\node[fmtw, left=of block8, 
            xshift=-5mm]        (block9) {block8};% shift to left

\node[fmtw, below=of block8]    (block10) {block9};      

\node[fmtw, right=of block2]    (block11) {block10};      

\node[fmtw, below=of block11,align=center,text width=3cm]   (block12) {Send requests for each aggregator (Section 3)}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block12]   (block13) {block12}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block13]   (block14) {block13}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block14]   (block15) {block14}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block15]   (block16) {block15}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block16]   (block17) {block16}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block17]   (block18) {block17}; 

\node[fmt, diamond,
    below=of block18, 
    inner sep=0]                (block19) {block18};
    
\node[fmtw, left=of block19, 
        xshift=-5mm]            (block20) {block19};% moving a little to left

 
\node[fmtw, below=of block19]   (block21) {END};   
    
% Arrows
  \draw[-latex] (block1) edge (block2);
  \draw[-latex] (block2) edge (block3);
  \draw[-latex] (block3) edge (block4);
  \draw[-latex] (block4) edge node[pos=0.3,inner sep=0pt,right=3pt]{Yes}(block6)
     (block4) edge node[pos=0.4,inner sep=0pt,below=3pt]{No}(block5);
  \draw[-latex] (block6) edge (block7);  
  \draw[-latex] (block7) edge (block8);        
  \draw[-latex] (block8) edge node[pos=0.4,inner sep=0pt,below=3pt]{Yes}(block9)
     (block8) edge node[pos=0.3,inner sep=0pt,right=3pt]{No}(block10);
% \draw[->] (block10) -| (block11);  
  \draw[-latex] (block11) edge (block12);  
  \draw[->] (block12) edge (block13);
  \draw[->] (block13) edge (block14);
  \draw[->] (block14) edge (block15);
  \draw[->] (block15) edge (block16);
  \draw[->] (block16) edge (block17);
  \draw[->] (block17) edge (block18);
  \draw[->] (block18) edge (block19);
  \draw[-latex] (block19) edge node[pos=0.4,inner sep=0pt,below=3pt]{Yes}(block20)
     (block19) edge node[pos=0.3,inner sep=0pt,right=3pt]{No}(block21);
%     \draw[->] (block20) |- (block7);
     
  \draw[->] (block10.east) --++(0.15cm,0cm) |- (block11.west); 
  \draw[->] (block20.west) --++(-4cm,0cm) |- (block7.west);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to fix Yes and No in the flow chart

Comment: @Husam Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my answer on your previous question.

In comparison to it, that nodes require that text in them can automatically split into more lines. Assuming, that text should be center align in nodes, you only need change definition of `box` style to:

```
       box/.style = {draw, text width=32mm, align=center, minimum height=9mm},
```

and due to inserted new node in branch "A" accordingly change coordinates of drawn arrows:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm and 5mm,
      start chain = A going below,
      start chain = B going below,
       arr/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb},
       box/.style = {draw, text width=32mm, align=center, minimum height=9mm},
  decision/.style = {diamond, draw, minimum width=24mm, inner sep=0},
every edge/.style = {arr},
every edge quotes/.style={auto=right, font=\footnotesize},
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\node[box, rounded rectangle]   {START};    % A-1
\node[box]      {block1};
\node[box]      {Track the highest Peak during the billing Cycle};
\node[decision] {block3};                   % A-4
\node[box]      {block5};
\node[box]      {block6};
\node[decision] {block7};                   % A-7
\node[box]      {block9};
    \end{scope}
\node (C-1)     [box, left=of A-4]  {block4};
\node (C-2)     [box, left=of A-7]  {block8};
    \draw   (A-4) edge ["Yes"] (C-1)
            (A-7) edge ["Yes"] (C-2);
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=B, join= by arr}]
\node[box,
      right=of A-2] {block10};  % B-1
\node[box]      {Send requests for each aggregator (Section 3)};
\node[box]      {block12};
\node[box]      {block13};
\node[box]      {block14};
\node[box]      {block15};
\node[box]      {block16};
\node[box]      {block17};
\node[decision] {block18};                  % B-9
\node[box]      {END};
    \end{scope}
\node (B-11)    [box, left=of B-9] {block19};
% Arrows
\coordinate[left=of C-2] (aux);
\draw[arr]  (A-8.east) -- ++ (0.2,0) |- (B-1);
\draw[arr]  (B-9)  edge ["Yes"] (B-11);
\draw[arr]  (B-11) -| (aux) |- (A-5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]